# template function lookup second type based on first type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

In the below code the caller needs to supply two types to the function template. This works fine however there is a correlation between the types 'RT' and 'Type'. A simple example; if RT is 'Maritime' then Type is always 'NM'. So I am thinking the 'Type' is a bit redundant and maybe it could be removed? How can I accomplish this?

```
template<typename RT, typename Type>
RT make_obj(Object obj)
{
  return RT(
    obj.value1(),
    make_another_obj<Type>(obj.value2()));
}
```

Comment: btw there is a lots of irrelevant stuff in your code that causes it to be incomplete and not a [mcve]. You are basically asking how to map one type to another, and it should be not too difficult to make up an example that can be complete and self contained.

Comment: for example `Type make_obj( RT rt) { return {}; }` would be sufficient to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A simple example; if RT is 'Maritime' then Type is always 'NM'

If there is a one to one relation then you can use a trait and remove the redundant argument:

```
template <typename RT> struct Type_from_RT;
template <> struct Type_from_RT<Maritime> { using type = NM; };
// more specializations for other RTs ...

// for convenience:
template <typename RT> using Type_from_RT_t = Type_from_RT<RT>::type;

template<typename RT>
RT make_obj(Object obj)
{
  return RT(
    obj.value1(),
    make_another_obj<Type_from_RT_t<RT>>(obj.value2()));
}
```

Alternatively the `RT` types could supply a `type` member alias directly.